# How to redirect http:// to https:// like firebase hosting

Tags: angular, google-cloud-run

Firebase hosting already had https:// redirects, in the firebase.json. I have an Angular app, and to prepare for SSR, I migrated from firebase hosting to Cloud Run. At first I didn't know whether I was supposed to mess with Angular Universal or something to do this, I seen a similar question on here but it was answered with Nginx, which is not what I need.

I tried to do really dumb things with the server.ts file and that was not the answer at all. I honestly do not know exactly where to start. I have scoured google for the answer, including of google cloud run docs here:

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/public

but I have no idea where to go from here.

Answer (score 2):

The Cloud Run Front-end handles both HTTP and HTTPS. From Cloud Run to your software running inside the container is over HTTP port 8080 (the current default port that might change).

Since your code is running HTTP, you need to detect the HTTP headers that Cloud Run includes with requests. This header is `x-forwarded-proto`. This header tells you what protocols the client is using to connect to the Cloud Run Front-end. If the protocol is HTTP, then your software needs to send a redirect (HTTP 301) to the correct URI.

The following code snipped with read the Request Headers, check `x-forwarded-proto` for HTTP and redirect if True.

```
if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] != 'https')
    res.redirect('https://' + req.hostname + req.url)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with Firebase hosting, you can keep using it together with Cloud Run: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run

This lets you keep the nice features of Firebase hosting, like forcing HTTPS, rewriting URLs, and pointing some URLs to static content.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. The only limitation is Firebase's 60-second request timeout which should not affect most deployments.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are only able to run Cloud run at a particular location on your server, not the actual base-level domain.

Answer (score -2):

If you're allowed to make a .htaccess file, try this:

1. Create a .htaccess in your site's home directory
2. Add these lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

3. Reload your website, and give it a minute to register the changes.

Basically this forces any URL used to access the site, to an HTTPS:// URL.

https://www.siteground.com/kb/how-to-force-ssl-with-htaccess/

Comment: I believe that this answer will work with Cloud Run hosting an Apache instance. I have deployed Apache in Cloud run, I have not verified that .htaccess works (I do not know of a reason that it will not work).